# Upgrading AspectJ 1.8.1 to 1.9.8 and Integrate with Gradle 7 + Java 11 Fail To locate Aspectjrt.jar

Tags: java, gradle, ant, build.gradle, aspectj

I am in process of upgrading Java 8 based spring codebase ( gradle project ) to Java 11.
The project does contain AOP code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and it relies on these dependencies

```
org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.3.27.RELEASE
org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.1
org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1
```

The above dependencies after bumping up to 1.9.8:

```java
dependencies {
    ajc 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.9.8'
    implementation 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.9.8'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.8'
    aspects 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0'

    aspects "org.springframework:spring-aspects:${springVersion}"
    aspects "org.springframework:spring-tx:${springVersion}"
    aspects "org.springframework:spring-orm:${springVersion}"
```

Based on the following documentation, AspectJ 1.8.x is NOT compatible with java 8+ :
https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/blob/master/docs/release/JavaVersionCompatibility.adoc

And Java 17 is what we are planning to upgrade to eventually.
official document on AspectJ 1.9.8 and its support: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/kriegaex/org.aspectj/blob/4b9d86acd096e5ee9e108ff0a450c420c880b6ea/docs/dist/doc/README-198.html

After successfully upgraded gradle 5 to gradle 7, attempt to running `gradlew clean build` fail on the following error:

```
> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/someDir/someService/src/main/java/someCode.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

[ant:iajc] [warning] couldn't find aspectjrt.jar on classpath, checked: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jrt-fs.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.persistence/persistence-api/1.0/5725f57873e05e068803e2bf9d5a8ea3740ffec5/persistence-api-1.0.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.19/a60d729e20daa34220b63be28d1b3cd20c1128e8/spring-aspects-5.3.19.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.3.19/f0b442718e67000845e8662ea10f138d7c47a3ae/spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.3.19/963b297aed7a1f9252cf4d925e6178190448ec81/spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.persistence/persistence-api/1.0/5725f57873e05e068803e2bf9d5a8ea3740ffec5/persistence-api-1.0.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.19/a60d729e20daa34220b63be28d1b3cd20c1128e8/spring-aspects-5.3.19.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.3.19/f0b442718e67000845e8662ea10f138d7c47a3ae/spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.3.19/963b297aed7a1f9252cf4d925e6178190448ec81/spring-orm-5.3.19.jar
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine superclass of missing type org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine superclass of missing type org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] classpath error: unable to find org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint (check that aspectjrt.jar is in your classpath)
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] 10 errors, 1 warning
```

I have double checked and verified that the `aspectjrt.jar` exists in my home `.gradle` directory :

```
/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.9.8/7a5d13787d5268d415055eba51024fb7348fc533/aspectjrt-1.9.8.jar
```

however my existing `build.gradle` file doesn't seem to be checking for this directory for some reason....( which i suspect to be the root cause here)

my current build.gradle settings are as:

```java
configurations.all {
    transitive = false
}

compileJava {
    doLast {
        ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
        ant.iajc(
                source:"1.11",
                target:"1.11",
                destDir:sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.getAsPath(),
                maxmem:"512m", fork:"true",
                aspectPath:configurations.aspects.asPath,
                sourceRootCopyFilter:"**/*.java",
                classpath:"${configurations.compile.asPath}") {
                    sourceroots {
                        sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each {
                            srcDir ->
                            pathelement(location:srcDir.absolutePath)
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
}


configurations{
    ajc
    aspects
    aspectCompile
    compile {
        extendsFrom aspects
    }
}
....

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    classifier = 'sources'
}
```

And I have checked all details on the AjcTask(iajc) installation on the official doc, unfortunately the steps are all written for maven project:
https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/printable.html#antTasks-install

If anyone happen to know link / guide on addressing this issue, will truly appreciate the sharing !

Comment: _"unfortunately the steps are all written for maven project"_ - Correction: No, they are written for an Ant project.

Comment: _Based on the following documentation, AspectJ 1.8.x is NOT compatible with java 8+_: I just noticed this sentence when reading the question again and want to ask, if you really read that page. AspectJ 1.8.x **is** compatible with Java 8. If by "8+" you mean to exclude 8 and want to say ">8", then the statement is (partly) correct. If you use Java  9+ (>=9) features, you need a more recent AspectJ version. But if you just run the application on a more recent JDK, but still compile to target 8, you are fine with AspectJ 1.8.x.

Answer (score 0):

> I have double checked and verified that the `aspectjrt.jar` exists in my home `.gradle` directory

Well, that might be true, but obviously it is not on the Ant task's classpath (added line breaks to limit horizontal scrolling):

```
[ant:iajc] [warning] couldn't find aspectjrt.jar on classpath, checked
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jrt-fs.jar
  /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.persistence/persistence-api/1.0/5725f57873e05e068803e2bf9d5a8ea3740ffec5/persistence-api-1.0.jar
  /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.19/a60d729e20daa34220b63be28d1b3cd20c1128e8/spring-aspects-5.3.19.jar
  /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.3.19/f0b442718e67000845e8662ea10f138d7c47a3ae/spring-tx-5.3.19.jar
  /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.3.19/963b297aed7a1f9252cf4d925e6178190448ec81/spring-orm-5.3.19.jar
  /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.persistence/persistence-api/1.0/5725f57873e05e068803e2bf9d5a8ea3740ffec5/persistence-api-1.0.jar
  /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.19/a60d729e20daa34220b63be28d1b3cd20c1128e8/spring-aspects-5.3.19.jar
  /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.3.19/f0b442718e67000845e8662ea10f138d7c47a3ae/spring-tx-5.3.19.jar
  /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.3.19/963b297aed7a1f9252cf4d925e6178190448ec81/spring-orm-5.3.19.jar
```

Fix that, and you should be fine.

BTW, why are you using an ancient Ant task from Gradle and not something like [Freefair](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/8.4/reference/)?

Comment: Thanks for chime in first of all.  
quoting `but obviously it is not on the Ant task's classpath` , yea...this is exact the problem that I am trying to solve, having no luck to find a helpful guide yet...
`BTW, why are you using an ancient Ant task from Gradle and not something like Freefair?` Well...the short answer would be it is an ancient service ( built more than 6 years ago ) if Java 8 still alive, we would never touch it.  Btw, is Freefair a must-have for upgrading to Java 11 for AOP code base ?

Comment: No, it is just an easier way to use the AspectJ compiler from Gradle. I know all about AspectJ + Maven, but never use Gradle. But I used Freefair in the past to answer AspectJ + Gradle related questions, and it is quite easy to use with way less boilerplate than you have now. Besides, I am not an Ant user either and certainly never used Ant from Gradle before. Therefore, without a full, minimal reproducer on GitHub, I cannot help you.

Comment: I would like to help you better, but I need you to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) project on GitHub - not your original code, just a minimal reproducer. I won't create one from scratch.

Comment: Happy new year Kriegaex!  I would like to try out the Freefair approach and wonder where would be a good starting point for migrating the AjcTask to Freefair,  would appreciate your advice on this :)

Comment: Did you use your favourite web search engine with search terms like "freefair gradle aspectj"?  You should easily find [this page](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/current/reference/#_aspectj_plugins). If you have any follow-up inquiries, please create a new question on SO. But then, please, please do not ignore my request for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) again. SO not a discussion forum. People here like to inspect reproducible problems and write spot-on answers without much back-and-forth debate. I already wasted time with this question without any result.

Comment: unfortunately I tried to create MCVE,  it is not possible for me without leaking proprietary source code, there is a lot of business logic which is shared across other services. That is not a choice for me.   
As a Update,  the error `[error] classpath error: unable to find org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint (check that aspectjrt.jar is in your classpath)` is resolved after I added this line in the `dependencies` block in gradle file `implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.8'` .

Comment: However, I am still getting the rest of [ant: iajc] errors which I have no clue about the root cause
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
[ant:iajc] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=180 AopXmls=#0
[ant:iajc]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
...
```

Comment: _"I tried to create MCVE, it is not possible for me without leaking proprietary source code"_ That is a statement unworthy of a developer. You can rename packages, classes, methods, modify the code to do some dummy stuff. Nobody needs your proprietary code. Strip off functionality from your original code step by step, as much as you can, until only a minimal skeleton reproducing the problem remains. Then anonymise it. **That** is an MCVE. Like this, I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle

```
...skip...

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-parameters"
}

task compileAspectJ(type: JavaExec) {

classpath = configurations.compileClasspath + files('/home/demo/aspectj1.9/lib/aspectjrt.jar','/home/demo/aspectj1.9/lib/aspectjtools.jar','/home/demo/aspectj1.9/lib/aspectjweaver.jar')

    setMainClass('org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main')
    args = [
            '-classpath', classpath.asPath,
            '-inpath', 'build/classes/java/main',
            '-d', 'build/ajcOutput',
            '-aspectpath', 'build/classes/java/main',
            '-source', '17', // or whatever source compatibility you need
            '-target', '17', // or whatever target compatibility you need
            '-g:lines,vars,source',
            '-sourceroots', 'src/main/java'
    ]
}

compileJava.dependsOn compileAspectJ
```

Run `gradle build`

Comment: Is `compileAspectJ` task a replacement for ant task `iajc` here ?
This does't seem to be applicable for our service, with the following code `files('/home/demo/aspectj1.9/lib/aspectjrt.jar','/home/demo/aspectj1.9/lib/aspectjtools.jar','/home/demo/aspectj1.9/lib/aspectjweaver.jar')`  you are trying to define a customized location of aspectj jar files here, while we don't store these jar anywhere other than their default directory. Correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: I think `compileAspectJ` task can replace ant task iajc. You can observe whether its parameter names are corresponding.
At least my gradle build can pass successfully without error messages.
In addition, since you did not provide more source code about how you use AspectJ, if you have a minimal test example project, then others can test and verify based on the source code of this project.

Comment: Direct reference to `files('/home/demo/aspectj1.9/lib/aspectjrt.jar','/home/demo/aspectj1.9/lib/aspectjtools.jar','/home/demo/aspectj1.9/lib /aspectjweaver.jar')` is to confirm this first, you can use gradle build.
Once passed, indicating that there is no problem with the concept, the next step is to find another setting method. Do not write a fixed file path but quote the setting method.